# Is a PCIe 2.x compatible with Intel 915G chipset?

Tags: hardware-rec, pci-express

I am trying to update an old system.
I am thinking of a newer video card, and most are **PCIe 2.x**.  I know that they are backward-compatible with **PCIe 1.x** motherboards, but what about the chipset?

I have an **Intel 915G**, and it appears it can only handle PCIe 1.x.

Comment: I have no hands on experience here, so not an answer, but I'm under the impression these are supposed to be both backwards and forwards compatible in the sense that they'll present themselves to a PCIe 1 device as a PCIe 1 card, so there's no risk of the chipset going weird (much like SATA devices do, actually).  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

915G data sheet says it supports PCIx16, whether your motherboard has the 16x slot is another thing.

[image]